# Dúvida de dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário, posicionamento

Como faço para contar elementos do dicionário?

dado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso implementar uma função conta telefones, que recebe uma agenda e retorna a quantidade de números de telefone registrados.

Se houver telefones repetidos (o exemplo agenda_melhor1 tem!),
conte as repetições (resposta 4)

O código que criei e nao está dando certo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ou seria algo assim?                                                                                           def conta_telefones(agenda):
    cont = 0
    for pessoa in agenda:
        for telefone in pessoa:
            if agenda[pessoa][telefone] is not None:
                cont += len(pessoa[telefone])    
    return cont

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Mas apenas para adiantar um dos problemas (não testei o código, então não sei se é o único problema): a chave dos dicionários é "telefone**s**" (no plural). mas vc está tentando acessar "telefone" (no singular). Também não entendi porque o resultado deve ser 4, sendo que só um dos telefones se repete.

Comment: Olá Tatiane, novas dúvidas sobre código em Python, estás a fazer um trabalho académico?

Comment: Reforçando, coloca os dados JSON e código python com acentos ``` ```, assim é apresentado de forma correta, tornando-se mais fácil para ctrl - c.

Answer (score 0):

Tatiane, este é um pattern de `map => reduce`.
Você aplica uma função nos dados, e depois soma tudo:

```
from functools import reduce

def conta_telefones(agenda):

    comprimentos = map(lambda dados:len(dados.get('telefones')), 
                       agenda.values())

    return reduce(lambda total, v: total + v,
                  comprimentos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que você quer trabalhar com as chaves do dicionário no laço `for`. Neste caso, use:

`for pessoa in agenda.keys():`